# Angular CanDeactivate Guard not working with Sweet Alert JS

Tags: angular, typescript, guard, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I'm using `CanDeactivate` guard in Angular with [Sweet Alert js](https://sweetalert2.github.io). But ok click is not fired. I'm new to Angular Please assist. Here is the code with sweet alert. Sweet Alert is displayed but ok click not working.

```
export class QuestionEditGuard implements CanDeactivate<FeedbackQuestionEditPage> {
    canDeactivate(component: FeedbackQuestionEditPage): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
        if (component.questionForm.dirty) {
            const question = component.questionForm.get('description').value || 'New Question';
            swal.fire({
                title: 'Hey there!!',
                text: `Navigate away and lose all changes to ${question}?`,
                type: 'warning',
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonText: 'OK',
            }).then((result) => {
                return true;
            });

            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

But with normal `Confirm` it works.

```
export class QuestionEditGuard implements CanDeactivate<FeedbackQuestionEditPage> {
    canDeactivate(component: FeedbackQuestionEditPage): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
        if (component.questionForm.dirty) {
            const question = component.questionForm.get('description').value || 'New Question';
            return confirm(`Navigate away and lose all changes to ${question}?`);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to `return` the `Swal.fire` function as you do with the normal `confirm`

```
export class QuestionEditGuard implements CanDeactivate<FeedbackQuestionEditPage> {
    canDeactivate(component: FeedbackQuestionEditPage): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
        if (component.questionForm.dirty) {
            const question = component.questionForm.get('description').value || 'New Question';
            return swal.fire({ // <- return here
                title: 'Hey there!!',
                text: `Navigate away and lose all changes to ${question}?`,
                type: 'warning',
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonText: 'OK',
            }).then((result) => {
                if (result.value) {  // check if OK pressed
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            })
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```